# Tkinter - how to capture a menubar submenu button has been pressed?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In the code below when choosing menubar item Recipient/email/ and an address is selected how can I capture what email address button has been pressed? I have found examples of using a drop down menu but I don't know how I would apply it the code below.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class MenuBar(Menu):
    def __init__(self, ws):
        Menu.__init__(self, ws)

        recipient= Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        address = Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        for email in ('joe@joe.com', 'sam@sam.com'):
            address.add_command(label=email)
        recipient.add_cascade(label='email', menu=address)
        self.add_cascade(label='Recipient', menu=recipient)

class MenuTest(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws=MenuTest()
    ws.title('email recipient')
    ws.geometry('400x300')
    ws.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a method that handles menu selections and accepts the email string as an argument

```
def __init__(self, ws):
    # yadda yadda
    for email in ('joe@joe.com', 'sam@sam.com'):
        address.add_command(
            label=email,
            # add a command to call your selection handler
            # using a lambda to pass 'email' as an argument
            command: lambda e = email: self.on_selection(e)
        )

def on_selection(self, email):  # this method will be fired on menu selection
    print(email)  # do whatever you need to do with the selected email
```